# Template-based facelet tag library

Tags: jsf, facelets, icefaces

I want to create a facelet component which is backed by template.

Something like that:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.isStepActive('step0')}">
  <composition template="wizard-step.jspx">
    <ui:define name="title">Step One</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="text"><p>This describes the step</p></ui:define>
  </composition>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.isStepActive('step1')}">
  <composition template="wizard-step">
    <ui:define name="title">Step Two</ui:define>
(...)
```

Is seems not to work as the content of wizard-step.jspx is put on any page no matter what renders returns (it seems like the ui: tags are evaluated before all other tags.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want?
A normal custom tag is not powerful enough in my case because it only supports xml attributes but no child elements.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution and it's pretty easy.

Just use a normal taglib and use < ui:insert> and < ui:define> like that:

```
<my:wizardStep>
<ui:insert name="title"><h2>The header comes here</h2>/ui:insert>
</<my:wizardStep>
```

And in the tag definition:

```
<ui:composition>
<ui:insert name="title" />
(...)
```